# Close CSS Menu on click

Tags: css, menu, onclick

I have a pure CSS drop down menu that I would like to close when the user clicks an item in the menu.

Please resize the browser to under 768 px because that is when the drop down appears.

[This is the site](http://kyle-morrison.com/interzone/)

**Here is my code:**

```
<div class="nav">
    <input type="checkbox" id="toggle" />
    <label for="toggle" class="toggle" onclick></label>
    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Creative Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Updates</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!-- End of Navigation -->
```

and here is my css

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){
.menu { display: none; opacity: 0; width: 100%; position: absolute; right: 0; }
.menu > li { display: block; width: 100%; margin: 0; }
.menu > li > a { display: block; width: 100%; text-decoration: none; -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; box-sizing: border-box; }
.toggle { display: block; position: relative; cursor: pointer; -webkit-touch-callout: none; -webkit-user-select: none; user-select: none; }
#toggle:checked ~ .menu { display: block; opacity: 1;}
}
.toggle:after {
content: '☰';
display: block;
width: 100px;
margin: 33px 0;
padding: 10px 50px;
text-align: center;
font-size: 20px;
color: blue;
box-sizing: border-box; 
}

.toggle:hover:after{    
color: red;
}

.toggle:active:after{   
color: blue;
}   
#toggle:checked + .toggle:after{
content: '☰';
}
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to uncheck your checkbox without js...

Comment: Thanks, would you happen to have any suggestions on how to do that?

Comment: sure, to clarify these links aren't taking you to a different page right?

Comment: yes, they will be linking to anchors on the same page

Comment: for pure CSS  the use of tabindex instead input might be a way to do so : http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/krczi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, to do this with jquery (which I saw you already have on your page..):

```
$(function () {
    $('.menu').find('a').on('click', closeNav);
});
function closeNav() {
    jQuery("#toggle").attr('checked', false);
}
```